# Insert update and delete in servlet and jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

i am very new to servlet and jsp so i am trying to achieve a operation like view,add , update and delete but i dont have an idea to achieve this operation like how to forward a page and maintain session and pass value to jsp so kindly some could  help in right way.
i had gone many tutorial but no idea and here tried so for

Controller.java

```
    package servlet;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import db.Dbconnect;


    public class Controller extends HttpServlet 
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


        public Controller() 
        {
            super();
        }


        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
        {
        }


        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
        {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

             String nam = request.getParameter("name"); 
             String pass = request.getParameter("pass"); 
             String email = request.getParameter("emailid"); 
             String phono = request.getParameter("phone");


        }


        public  void view() throws ClassNotFoundException
        {

            try
            {
                String sql="select * from Reg";
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mine", "root", "android");
                Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);

                while(rs.next())
                {
                    rs.getString("name");
                    rs.getString("pass");
                    rs.getString("emailid");
                    rs.getString("phoneno");
                   System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));

                }

            } 
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return;

        }

        public  String insertuser() throws SQLException
        {

            String sql = "insert into Reg(name,pass,emailid,phoneno) values(?,?,?,?)";
            Connection con = null;
            PreparedStatement prep = null;

            try
            {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mine", "root", "android");
                prep = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                prep.setString(1, "nam");
                prep.setString(2, "pass");
                prep.setString(3, "email");
                prep.setString(4, "phono");
                prep.executeUpdate();
                prep.close();

            } 
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return "successfully added";
        }
        public  String update() throws SQLException
        {

            String sql = "update Reg set pass=?,emailid=?,phoneno=? where name=?";
            Connection con = null;
            PreparedStatement prep = null;

            try
            {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mine", "root", "android");
                prep = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                prep.setString(1, "nam");
                prep.setString(2, "pass");
                prep.setString(3, "email");
                prep.setString(4, "phono");
                prep.executeUpdate();
                prep.close();

            } 
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return "successfully update";
        }

public  String delete() throws SQLException
    {

        String sql = "delete form Reg where name=?";
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement prep = null;

        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mine", "root", "android");
            prep = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return "successfully delete";
    }


    }
```

Add.jsp::

```
<form action="/Controller" method="post">
User name:<input type="text" name="name" >
Password:<input type="password" name="pass">
Email-id<input type="text" name="emailid">
phone number:<input type="text" name="phone">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Update.jsp:

```
<form action="/Controller" method="post">
User name:<input type="text" name="name" >
Password:<input type="password" name="pass">
Email-id<input type="text" name="emailid">
phone number:<input type="text" name="phone">

<input type="submit" value="Update"/>
</form>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Vweb2</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>

    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>

  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Controller</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.Controller</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Controller</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

`View.jsp` and `delete.jsp` for this two page i dono how to retrieve information servlet to jsp

Comment: _how to forward a page_ use `request.getRequestDispatcher("/pagename.jsp").forward(request,response);` go through some tutorials, try what you got, then come..

Comment: Dont mistake is some body can update my code its useful to learn from all???

Answer (score 0):

For View.jsp  declare  form's method attribute as GET.

Do below,

```
 <form action="/Controller" method="get">
```

and Use

```
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {

       // Your rendering logic
    }
```

Similarly use delete / doDelete() methods for delete.jsp.

You also need to mention mappings in web.xml

Answer (score -1):

I think you get better help form this eg.
    http://danielniko.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/simple-crud-using-jsp-servlet-and-mysql/

Comment: While the link may be helpful, you should really edit in a summary from the link. If the link were ever to break, your answer would be useless to future visitors who come to this page with the same question. Hope this helps.